# Como hago una animacion en la navegacion interna

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen dia desarrolladores, como estas?

Mi pregunta es la sigueinte: 
Como puedo hacer en css posiblemente que al momento de pulsar un elemento del menu en el header de mi pagina me lleve a un elemento de la misma pagina mediante la navegacion interna con una transicion de scroll en la pagina.

Les agradeceria mucho, ojala hayan entendido.

Comment: te recomiendo leer [ask] pues se espera que las publicaciones muestren la duda, el código tratado y los errores obtenidos, saludos de paso haz el [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un par de formas de hacerlo, pero la que yo utilizo es con jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // El "efecto" se le agrega a todos los elementos <a>
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Al hacer click te llevará a lo que tenga href=""
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();   
      // El hash es el valor del link
      var hash = this.hash;

// La velocidad de la animación puedes modificarla, 1000 = 1 segundo

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

No está demás mencionar que debes importar jQuery para que funcione.